# Proof that design matrices with entries near zero lead to high variance of least squares estimator

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, multicollinearity, linear-algebra

I asked this question on [Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276717/proof-that-design-matrices-with-small-entries-lead-to-high-variance-of-least-s) but it might be better-suited to this site.

I have a linear model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim (0_n, \sigma^2 I_n)$. The matrix $X$ is $n \times p$. If $\hat \beta$ is the least squares estimator of $\beta$ and $\lvert x_{ij} \rvert \leq 1$ for all $i, j$, then I want to show that $\text{Var}(\hat \beta_j) \geq \sigma^2 / n$ for $j = 1, \dots, p$.

(I guess the point here is that matrices $X$ with small values lead to large variability in the least squares estimators for $\beta$.)

**My attempt:**

I know that $\hat \beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$, and $\text{Var}(\hat \beta) = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}$. I was thinking that if I had a formula for the diagonal entry of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ that might be handy, but I'm not sure where I am going with that. I was also thinking about the triangle inequality, but I'm not sure how to use it. One consequence of the assumption $\lvert x_{ij} \rvert \leq 1$ is that all entries in $X^T X$ will have absolute value less than $n$, right?

I was also playing with a toy $3 \times 2$ example for X, but that didn't seem to lead anywhere.

As I was thinking about this more, I've started to suspect that this problem is dealing with multicollinearity, without explicitly saying so. I've been trying to read about the mathematical formulation of multicollinearity, but I haven't found anything that looks like it can be used for my purposes.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Small values in X lead to very high $(X’X)^{-1}$

Comment: @Aksakal That is the suspicion that I have been getting, but I need a precise lower bound. I think that I need to use that $\lvert x_{ij}\rvert \leq 1$ somehow.

Comment: Lower abound of what?

Comment: @Aksakal I need to show that the variance of each component of $\hat \beta$ is at least $\sigma^2/n$ (see the beginning of the question above).

Comment: Assume that X are uncorrelated, this will simplify equations

Comment: You get large variability in the least square estimators for $\beta$ when a) $n-\text{rk}(X)$ is small, b) the variability in the last $p-1$ columns of $X$ (in the $p-1$ explanatory variables) is small. Notice that b) happens when $\sum_{j=1}^n(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_j)^2 $ is small for each $i$. Try playing with $x=(999,1000,1001)$ and $x=(500,1000,1500)$.